# -webkit-transform unsupported property

Tags: css, animation, webkit-transform, webkit-animation

I am trying to apply a transform (scale + translation) to a div in css:

```
.my-div {
  -ms-transform: scaleX(40%) scaleY(40%) translateX(-20%) translateY(-20%);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(40%) scaleY(40%) translateX(-20%) translateY(-20%);
  -moz-transform: scaleX(40%) scaleY(40%) translateX(-20%) translateY(-20%);
  -o-transform: scaleX(40%) scaleY(40%) translateX(-20%) translateY(-20%);
  transform: scale(40%) translateX(-20%) translateY(-20%);
}
```

Although this works in chrome, it doesn't work in safari.  Inspecting the element, you see that `-webkit-transform` and `transform` should apply, but I see warnings.  The warning says "Unsupported property value."

[image]

I've tried percentages & decimals, scale with one & two values, translate split into X and Y or combined into a single translate. Nothing works. The documentation states that this should work.

Any ideas?

Comment: we no more need prefixes for transform since decades, you can remove them and keep only `transform`

Comment: I tried removing those prefixes and only keeping the transform, but it still doesn't work in safari

Comment: use 0.45 instead of 45%. Maybe safari have issues with percentage

Comment: Have you tried splitting them out individually like so? https://css-tricks.com/css-individual-transform-properties-in-safari-technology-preview/

Comment: tried both of these - doesn't work. i still see unsupported property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded to 15.5 and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading from Safari 15.1 to 15.5 solved the problem. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score -1):

just use this one:

```css
.my-div {
  transform: scale(40%) translateX(-20%) translateY(-20%);
}
```

it must be work

Comment: Doesn't work. i still see unsupported property.

Comment: what's the version of your browser?

Comment: Safari Version 15.1

Comment: I upgraded to 15.5 and it solved the problem. Thank you!